# Induction problem involving two base cases and two assumptions of truth in recurrence relation

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-writing, proof-explanation, induction, recurrence-relations

I am unsure why I have to use two base cases of n=1 and n=2 and also assume truth for n=k and n=k+1 to prove by induction that n=k+2 is true.

I was trying to solve this question below:

> A sequence is given by the recurrence relation $u_{1}=5$,$\;u_{2}=13$, $\;u_{n+2}=5u_{n+1}-6u_{n}$,$\;n\ge1$. Prove that the general formula for the sequence is $u_{n}=2^n+3^n$.

My first attempt was just usual as normal induction problems, let n=1 for the base case and then assume truth for n=k and find that it is also true for n=k+1. However, the mark scheme says that:

> Let n=1,
> $\vdots$
> $\therefore$ true for n=1.
>
> Let n=2,
> $\vdots$
> $\therefore$ true for n=2.
>
> Assume truth for n=k and n=k+1,
> $u_{k}=2^k+3^k$
> $u_{k+1}=2^{k+1}+3^{k+1}$
>
> Let n=k+2,
> $\vdots$
> $\therefore$ true for n=k+2.
>
> $\therefore$ The proposition is true for n=1 and n=2, and if true for n=k and n=k+1, it is also true for n=k+2. By the principle of mathematical induction, the proposition is true for $\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}^+, n\ge1.$

My question is the following:

1. Why do we need to show the case that it is true for n=k+2 and not for n=k+1?
2. Can we assume truth for both n=k and n=k+1 at the same time? In a usual induction problem, we assume truth for n=k and then see if this is also true for n=k+1. Then, in this case, wouldn't that already satisfy the condition since n=k and n=k+1 are true (assumed to be true)?
3. Why do we need two base cases of n=1 and n=2?

Comment: About 1) and 2): **Usual** induction works this way: prove $f(1)$ holds, then suppose $f(n)$ is true, then find a way of deducing that $f(1)$ and $f(n)$ being true imply $f(n+1)$ is also true. Now, there is this thing called **strong** induction in which you prove $f(1)$ holds, then need to suppose $f(2)$, $f(3)$, $\ldots$, $f(n-1)$ and $f(n)$ are also true, then deduce all of them imply $f(n+1)$ is also true.
About 3): You need two base cases because your recurrence relation has order 2. Without knowing $u_2=13$, you have no way of computing $u_2$ with just the recurrence relation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer "why do we need to do this?", let's consider what can go wrong if we *don't*.

We're given the following three facts:

1. $u_1 = 5$
2. $u_2 = 13$
3. $u_{n+2} = 5 u_{n+1} - 6 u_n$

If we were able to complete the induction proof with a single base case, e.g. if we only had to prove that $u_1 = 2^1 + 3^1$, then if we changed the value of $u_2$ to, say, $14$, then none of the details of the proof would change, which means that we would still be able to prove that $u_n = 2^n + 3^n$ even though we now have a completely different sequence that must have its own closed form.

As for why we need to make two assumptions in the inductive hypothesis, notice that if you only assume that $u_k = 2^k + 3^k$ then you get as far as saying $u_{k+1} = 5 u_k - 6 u_{k-1} = 2^k + 3^k - 6 u_{k-1}$, but since you have no information (and have made no assumptions) about the behaviour of $u_{k-1}$ you can't progress any further.

*A small aside*: There is such a thing as *strong induction*, in which instead of assuming that $P(n)$ is true for some value $n = k$ you instead assume that $P(n)$ is true for *every* value $n = 1, 2, \ldots, k$ and use *that* to prove that $P(k + 1)$ is true, and hence $P(n)$ is true for every $n$. You can, in fact, prove that strong induction and regular induction are actually *equivalent*, i.e. you can turn any proof by strong induction into a proof by regular induction and vice versa, but usually applying strong induction is overkill.

We could, in fact, turn this proof into a more standard induction proof with a little trickery. Instead of having our statement $P(n)$ be "$u_n = 2^n + 3^n$", we could make it be "$u_n = 2^n + 3^n$ **and** $u_{n+1} = 2^{n+1} + 3^{n+1}$. If we do that, then the base case for $n = 1$ is exactly equal to the two initial values of $u_1 = 5$ and $u_2 = 13$, the induction hypothesis has the assumptions about $u_k$ and $u_{k+1}$ baked into it, and we wind up proving the formulas for $u_{k+1}$ and $u_{k+2}$, noting that the former is pretty trivial since we assumed the truth of that formula in the induction hypothesis.

Comment: +1 The closing paragraph cannot be stressed enough

Answer (score 1):

For your second question, you can assume $Q(n) = P(n)\& P(n+1)$ then using standard induction is equivalent to this induction. Remember here $Q(1)=P(1)\& P(2)$ which is the reason you need to proof for case $n=1$ and $n=2$.

Comment: It's a good point, but it's already been made at the end of the accepted answer.